# Nginx to serve angularjs content

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I'm using Nginx to serve angularjs file but I get 404 error. Here is the configuration of Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /projects/project/app;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

the app folder is composed by different folders. one folder `modules` contains the angularjs module

when I access to `localhost` nginx serves correctly the index page but when I click on a link in the page I get 404 error.

for instance in the html page I have the link '/foo' and a route with '/foo'

I don't understand if it is an angularjs misconfiguration or nginx

```
'use strict';

var fbAppModal = angular.module('App.foo', [
  'App.foo.controllers',
  'App.foo.services'
]);

fbAppModal.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/foo', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/foo.html',
        controller: 'FooController'
      });
  }
]);
```

in the html page I have just an href to `/foo`

Comment: What's the code? On what URL do you get a 404?

Comment: Edited the question. I get an 404 error when I click on /foo

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Open the development tools of your browser (F12 on windows), go to the network tab, click on the link. What is the URL, in the network tab, for which you get a 404 error? Also, post the html code.

Comment: the url for which I get is http://localhost/foo

Comment: OK. So a link that is supposed to just invoke change an angular route doesn't do it and sends an HTTP request instead. Post the HTML code.

Comment: Try change your `<a href = "/foo">` to `<a href = "#foo">` and see if it works or not ?